# Added class stays only after link is clicked twice

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

As the title suggests, I am adding a class to a link in a navbar with jQuery and jQuery Mobile. Unfortunately, the class is added but vanishes as soon as the page is done loading. Once I click the link a second time, it is added and stays.

My nav-bar looks like this:

```
<div data-role="header">
<div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#find_food" id="find_food_link">Find something to eat!</a></li>
        <li><a href="#invite_food" id="invite_food_link">Invite people!</a></li>
        <li><a href="#messages" id="messages_link">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#overlayPanel">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Because I want to keep the navigation bar the same across all subpages, I put it outside the pages-div but inside the body-tag as suggested by the documentation. I load the header with:

```
$(function(){
        $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar({ theme: "a" });
    });
```

Lastly, I try to add the "ui-btn-active" class to the link with:

```
$('#navbar').click(function(e){
    $(e.target.id).addClass("ui-btn-active");
})
```

If I use `e.preventDefault()` it stops the links from loading (as expected) and nothing works anymore. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Tushar It's a link so I guess page redirection is wanted. Also, wouldn't $(this) add the class to the navbar and not the actual link element?

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use the pagecontainer widget's **[transition event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-transition)** to add the class after all transitioning is done:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#find_food", function(){ 

    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainertransition", function( event, ui ) {
        var pID = ui.toPage.prop("id");
        $('#navbar [href="#' + pID + '"]').addClass("ui-btn-active");
    });

});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/g4kmjLo3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in doc ready:

```
$(function(){
    if(window.location.hash){
       $('#navbar').find('[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').addClass('ui-btn-active');
    }
    $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar({ theme: "a" });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue persists. If I look at it via Firebug, I see that the class is added but once loading is complete, it is gone again.